# Is there way to have Node redirect to a new page with JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to allow users to type a search query into a box on an index.html page and have it send them to a results.html page with results displayed.

Currently I have this working only on an index.html page where the old HTML is removed and replaced with the search results.

```
//Pertinent Node code:

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    res.redirect('index.html');

});

// A search box in index.html calls the /search below

app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const item_id = req.query.item_id;
    var json = {};

    var sql_query = "a SQL query";

    var result = connection.query(sql_query, function(err, result,         fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        json["result"] = result;

        console.log("Sent JSON to client");
        res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
    });
})

//Client-side:
    function get() {
        var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

        // Validate input to prevent injections
        var new_search = search.replace("<", "");
        var validated = new_search.replace(">", "");

        var url = host + "/search?search=" + validated;

        fetch(url, {method : 'GET'})

            .then(checkStatus)
            .then(function(responseText) {
                var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
                displaySearchResults(json, search);
            })

            .catch(function(error) {
            });
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is similar to what you might see on Google where clicking search send you to a new page with a url like: "https://www.google.com/searchresults?query=bicycles" that displays a different HTML page from index.html (such as results.html) with the JSON from index.html being moved to and processed in results.html.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Why not simply have a form with a target `search.html` and do the query there?  And, what does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: But how do I get the user's query to search.html to do the query? -- I assumed that it would involve redirecting to a search.html and somehow passing the JSON to search.html to be processed.

Comment: `<form action="search.html">`  That's all you need.  The browser will encode the form elements and pass them along in a GET request to `search.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some details to what Brad kindly mentioned in comments.. The full solution is:

```
<form action="search.html" method="GET" name="search">
```

Then in the Javascript file for search.html, access the form data with:

```
var search = window.location.search;
```

If you need to get the "?search=" out of the data, instead use:

```
var search = window.location.search.replace("?search=", "");
```